# Subtract two columns(Col1-Col2) and add remaining to next row in Col1

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to work on a logic which I cannot seem to figure out a way to do it.
**Problem:** 
I have three columns PrimaryKey, COl1 and COl2 as shown in below screenshot[image]

Let's take a new column Col3 = Col1-Col2,

I am adding the remaining in Col3 to Col1 of next row and again subtract it to get Col3.

Let us consider the table above and for

PrimaryKey=1 --> Col3 = 10.2 - 5 = 5.2.

This 5.2 must be added to Col1 of PrimaryKey=2 which is 
15 + 5.2 = 20.2.

Now again Col3 = 20.2 - 3 = 17.2, like this it has to iterate for next records.

I hope that I am clear enough in explaining my issue. Please let me know if you need any further explanation.

*The table provided is just a sample table, The actual table that I am working is very large.

Thank you.

Comment: Please edit your question and show the results, preferably as a text table

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, you want the cumulative value of col2 subtracted from the cumulative of col1.  In SQL Server 2012+, you would do:

```
select t.*,
       sum(col2 - col1) over (order by primary key)
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a self-join on the original table, but there's a danger if the primary key isn't complete, such as from deleting records at some point. Here I use a self-join with ROW_NUMBER to create a definitely sequential key - this allows me to join [this row number] to [this row number + 1] (sample data included in case anyone else has a better method):

```
DECLARE @YourTable TABLE (PrimaryKey INT IDENTITY(1,1), COL1 FLOAT, COL2 FLOAT)
INSERT INTO @YourTable
        ( COL1, COL2 )
VALUES 
      (10.2, 5.0)
    , (15.0, 3.0)
    , (5.7, 6)
    , (9.0, 5.5)

; WITH TableRanked
AS (
    SELECT PrimaryKey ,
           COL1 ,
           COL2
           , COL3 = COL1 - COL2
           , RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY PrimaryKey)
    FROM @YourTable
    )
SELECT tr.PrimaryKey ,
       tr.COL1 ,
       tr.COL2 ,
       tr.COL3
       , COL1Next = COALESCE(trNext.COL1, 0)
       , COL4 = tr.COL3 + COALESCE(trNext.COL1, 0)
FROM TableRanked tr
    LEFT JOIN TableRanked trNext
        -- Here's where the magic happens:
        ON trNext.RowNum = (tr.RowNum + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2012 you can use LEAD. This will get you the same results as what Russel posted but with better performance:

```
DECLARE @YourTable TABLE (PrimaryKey INT IDENTITY(1,1), COL1 FLOAT, COL2 FLOAT)
INSERT INTO @YourTable (COL1, COL2 )
VALUES  (10.2, 5.0), (15.0, 3.0), (5.7, 6), (9.0, 5.5);

SELECT *, (COL1 - COL2) + LEAD(COL1,1,0) OVER (ORDER BY PrimaryKey)
FROM @YourTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if this query helps:

```
DECLARE @n int 
SELECT @n = count(*) from @yourTable
DECLARE @counter int 
SELECT @counter = MIN(PrimaryKeyCol) from @yourTable
DECLARE @col3 = 0

WHILE (@counter <= @n)
 SELECT @col3 = @col3 + Col1 - Col2 from @yourTable where PrimaryKeyCol = @counter
Print @col3
@counter = @counter + 1
END
```